# Divide divs Evenly over entire length of another div

Tags: html, css

I have:

[image: How it should kinda look]

And as you can see it is numbered from 1-16. (This train has 16 axles.)
But, you can also scroll to the right ( Because of the text-fields under it. )
But when i scroll right:

[image: What it does]

You can see the numbering does not take 100% of the whole scrolable div. How do i do this so the axles (nr 1 / 16) are evenly divided from left to right??
The black box is the train.

Code:

```
<div id="center">
<?php
    //Train is send here//
    $add_train = $database->train_add();
?>
    Train: <?php echo $_POST['train_name']; ?>
    <!--Here we make the number of fields based on the number of axles-->
    <div id="axle_bogie_border">
    <!--The show axles are the number of checkboxes (Filled in by a user)-->
        <div id="show_axles">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <?php  
                $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                    if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                    for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                        echo "<td>" . "<div id='axle_figure'>" . $i . "</div>" . "</td>";
                    }   
                }
            ?>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br /> <br />
        <div id="show_bogies">
            <?php  
                $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                    if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                    for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                        echo "<input type='text' name='bogies[$i]'>";
                    }   
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#axle_bogie_border {
    background-image: url("../Images/add_train.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

#axle_figure {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background: orange;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#show_axles table{
    margin-top: 11%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#show_bogies {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: We really need a brief example of the output **HTML** to help

Comment: Is the number of axles always the same?

Comment: @DarkAshelin No. #paulie_D What do you mean?? everything is here xD

Comment: @Mitch You've supplied PHP...we need the output HTML to make sense of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are rendering the axles as `<td>`'s. If you just set your `<table>` to have `width: 100%`, it should fill the width of the entire screen.

```
table{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yapotuno/1/)

If this is not what you are looking, I must have misunderstood what you want. If so please give some extra info.